# Data not formatting correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to send the UserID of a created user to my database. I want to then reference data inside of the userID in the database.

In regards to the issue, I'm unaware of how L2GIZ7Sx-e-AALSJp4g and the others below were generated. The UserIDs are then attached to this identifier.

[image: The userID is the content of a data location]

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(User => {
    console.log("user id: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("Users").push(UserID);
    console.log("user logged in");
    alert("You have been signed in");
});
```

I would like the data to be stored as,

```
+Users
   +userid
        data about user
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `push()` on a location, Firebase generates a unique key under that location (the values starting with `-L` in your screenshot).

If you want to instead determine the name of the child node yourself, you should use `child(...)` instead of `push()`:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(User => {
    console.log("user id: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    var UserID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("Users").child(UserID).set(true);
    console.log("user logged in");
    alert("You have been signed in");
});
```

The above sets the value of the node to `true`, since Firebase won't store a node without a value.

Comment: Yes I see, thanks very much. For some reason my onAuthStateChanged will almost always trigger twice, do you any ideas for a possible work around. Also for some reason this results in the previous login being posted to the database. No worries if you don't, I'll try and figure it out.